# Using shift() and push() to loop array values vs. using a counter variable, what is the best approach?

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through a set of images within an array of animation frames. There are 7 images, and looping from 1-7 completes the animation. I need this animation to loop indefinitely, but I was wondering which of these is the best approach:

**Loop by modifying array**

```
/* Pull image from start of array. */
var image = frames.shift();
/* Process image. */
...
/* Add image back to end of array. */
frames.push(image );
```

**Loop using counter variable**

```
/* Pull image by counter offset. */
var image = frames[counter];
/* Process image. */
...
/* Increment or reset counter value. */
counter + 1 === frames.length ? counter = 0 : counter = counter + 1;
```

Is there a reason I'd chose one over the other? Alternatively, is there a better approach to this?

Comment: I'd use `counter % frames.length`. Array operations are rather heavy and `shift` causes the array items' indexes to be re-enumerated, while a property lookup is quite cheap.

Comment: FWIW, you can loop around with the counter using the modulus operator: `counter = (counter + 1) % frames.length;` *edit:* What Fabrício said ;)

Comment: Ah I hadn't considered modulus at all. How simple!

Comment: If you felt like being fancy, you could loop over them once and say `image.next = frames[(i + 1) % frames.length];`.  Then in your animation just hold on to the last image you processed, and say something like `image = image.next;` and never bother with arrays or counters again... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying the array is going to be more expensive than simply using a variable to keep track of your position in the array. The better way to do this, *if* you're looping indefinitely, seems to just be to use a `while` loop (rather than using a `for` loop where you reset the counter inside):

```
var i = 0;
while (true) {
    doSomething to array[i];

    i = (i+1) % array.length;
}
```

*However* if your goal really is having an animation proceed indefinitely every time a given interval elapses, a loop isn't ideal at all. Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) instead.

```
var frames = ...; //your images
var i = 0;
function animate() {
    do something to frames[i];
    i = (i+1) % array.length;
}

setInterval(animate, time_between_runs);
```

where `time_between_runs` is how much time should elapse before the function is called again.

Comment: Having an *"array of animation frames"* does not sound like such a `while` loop would be the right choice here. Anyways, using a counter is certainly the right choice.

Comment: @Felix True, I guess I meant as opposed to a for-loop which was modifying the counter internally. I'll update.

Comment: As a note I'm actually using `setInterval` for this. :-) *Edit: Ah, you've added that to your answer anyway.*

Comment: @James Oh ok, somehow I thought I saw the phrase 'for loop' somewhere...my mistake. Anyway, go with the variable, don't change the array. :)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to ditch the array and use a linked list.

Make each frame an object that points to the next object. The last one then points to the first. Then all you need to do is reference the next object.

```
var curr = first; // reference to first frame object

setInterval(function() {

    // process image
    curr.image.doSomething();

    // proceed to next
    curr = curr.next;

}, 1000);
```

No counters to mess with this way.

---

Setting up the linked list is usually pretty simple, and can likely be done with just a little modification to the current code that's setting up the Array.

```
var first = new Frame(); // This is your entry point
var current = first;        // This holds the current frame during setup

for (var i = 0; i < totalFrames; i++) {
    current.next = new Frame();   // Make the current reference a new frame
    current = current.next;          // Make the new frame current
}

current.next = first; // circular reference back to the first.

function Frame() {
    // set up this frame
}
```

Then `first` is your starting point.

---

Or the linking could be done within the `Frame` constructor.

```
var first = new Frame(null); 
var current = first;

for (var i = 0; i < totalFrames; i++) {
    current = new Frame(current);
}

current.next = first;

function Frame(currFrame) {
    // link this frame to the given one
    if (currFrame)
        currFrame.next = this;

    // set up the rest of this frame
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively a circular linked list also can be used I think. To turn an array of objects into a circular linked list:

```
frames.forEach(function(elem, index) { 
    elem.next = frames[index + 1] || frames[0];
});
```

And now you can do something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    frame = frame.next;
    ....
}, delay);
```